# Flow and logic - always testing for direct condition desired. !(!n) != n

Tags: php, if-statement, nested, logic, structure

Sorry in advance, I just don't know how to word this question nor look for it.
I feel like there should be a name for it, some sort of Principle, or Problem, but I don't know it. My title probably doesn't make sense either but I hope it will give enough of a hint.

I want to decide on a way to structure my code for a project. Specifically, nested conditions. In cases where you can't smack them together using AND, etc.

```
sell_insurance($person): bool {
    if ($person->healthy() === true) {
        if ($person->rich() === true) {
            print 'sold!';
            return true;
        }
        print 'not enough money';
        return false;
    }
    print 'too risky to sell';
    return false;
}
```

Versus:

```
sell_insurance($person): bool {
    if ($person->healthy() !== true) {
        print 'too risky';
        return false;
    }
    if ($person->rich() !== true) {
        print 'too poor';
        return false;
    }
    print 'sold!';
    return true;
}
```

I think the latter is easier to read, and if there was going to be like 50 nested `if`s it would be just ugly. But, I want to make sure I will not run into issues down the line. Something unexpected I won't see from here.

These tests are simple. One thing I'm afraid of, is that `not(not a)` doesn't necessarily equal `a`. Sometimes we might expect logic to be boolean when in fact it might not be. I might test `person->healthy() !== false`, but I might not realize that instead of being `true`, it might be a string `'almost'`. Or something less stupid.

My other concern, is, how to put this? The latter structure *defaults* to `true`. It feels less secure than the first approach.

Question to someone with more experience - what are up/downsides to the each approach? Which structure do you stick to, or do you shuffle them around? Thanks

I am learning PHP but I suppose this more or less applies to any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those kind of situation several approuches are possible two of them are: 
**Using a [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement** to make everything more compact and readable.
But, as Kolos pointed out, it depends on your priorities and general scenarios...

You can even get rid of the logic operators, sometimes I use something like this below, to arrive to simple comparison statements:

```
$var= $person->healthy() ? 'true' : 'false';
 $var.=$person->rich() ? 'true' : 'false';

    switch ($var) {
case "truetrue":
 echo "SOLD!";
    break;
case "falsetrue":
 echo "too risky to sell";
    break;
case "truefalse":
 echo "too poor!";
    break;
default:
    echo "NO WAY!";
}
```

Another commonly used is the usage of one or more so-colled **guard clauses** at the start that covers "corner cases".
In your exemple being rich AND healthy is mandatory, so let's put this as guard clause:

```
if ($person->healthy() && $person->rich()) {
   print "SOLD!";
    return true;
} elseif($person->healthy()) {
    print "too poor...";
     return false;
} elseif($person->rich()) {
    print "too risky...";
     return false;
} else {
    print "NO WAY!";
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at this an other way, either the person is accepted or declined, what makes his request declined could all be shown for example:
if the person is poor and not healthy, you will only "see" that he is not healthy since you returned before checking that. 
It all depends on what you want as a priority not only structure wise.

The first approach indicates, that you HAVE to be healthy to get this item,
on the other hand the second one just adds some logic to it (this might not make sense)

If there were way more statements it would all depend on the priority, if you would return from each of them I would take the Second way, but it all depends on what makes more sense, what is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. This actually shines a new light on the issue that I didn't consider at all - as you said, with the priority of checks and intent of the function